# Why I'm unable to click using webBrowser control (VB .Net)

Tags: vb.net

I'm building a small browser using VB.Net webBrowser control,

I'm testing my apps using any web-sites, when I try to use [this web-site](https://www.gumtree.co.za/post.html) and trying to click on any category (Fashion, Pets, Events,...), I realize that nothing happens. I can't figure it out !!!
so, it's not working.

Please can you help?

Comment: Your javascript isn't enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. please how do I enable Javascript in VS 2013?

Comment: by the way, I tried couple of things I found in the web concerning how to enable JavaScript in IE but haven't solved the problem.